# How can I pass values to control properties from a fragment declaration?

Tags: sapui5

Say I have a fragment I'd like to reuse within my xml view:

`<core:Fragment fragmentName="<name>" type="XML" />`

And within that fragment, I have a number of controls. I'd like to pass a value to that fragment to set those controls' properties, say `width`. This is a basic feature in other frameworks, e.g. EmberJS: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/component-arguments-and-html-attributes/

How can I achieve this in SAPUI5?

I cannot pass parameters to the fragment from the parent view, right? I'm not going for dialogue or something similar that could be initialized from the controller. I was actually trying to make column definitions within a smart table more maintainable by replacing the 7-8 lines of xml they need by a reusable control/component/fragment/whatever.

---

So, after some more research, it appears what I am trying to do can only be done via "Custom Controls" which need to be created programmatically in JS:
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/39d25641086c42aaa745028e15562ba8

Comment: Store your properties in a JSONModel. Bind this model to your view. Your view and all fragments  within should have access to the properties.

Comment: That is a pretty wonky workaround for what I'm trying to do and completely deminishes the reusability I'm going for. I could just not use reusable XML as well.

Comment: I would say the approaches are not that different, but it seems to me like you want to rant more than finding a solution.

Comment: The approaches are very different - feel free to refer to the link I've posted in my question to see for yourself.

Comment: Binding a fragment to a model is very similar to the ember.js approach. Might require 2-3 extra lines of code but seems doable. But yes, building a custom control is much more complex than building an ember.js component.

Comment: @Leo Consider unaccepting the answer below. Unfortunately, [`XMLComposite` is deprecated](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.XMLComposite) since 1.88.

Comment: @Leo I'd suggest creating an enhancement request on [OpenUI5 GitHub](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues). Fragments are quite limited (See my issues [#2355](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2355) and [#2423](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2423)) and creating custom controls **properly** is something for "experts" only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slap some metadata around your fragment to level them up to composite controls. See documentation here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.86.0/#/topic/b83a4dcb7d0e46969027345b8d32fd44

A working example with some default settings (like growing for the list) and some dynamic settings like the text in the label or the binding of the list in the fragment

MyControl.js

```
window.sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/XMLComposite"
], function(XMLComposite) {
  "use strict";

  return XMLComposite.extend("my.name.space.controls.MyControl", {
    metadata: {
      library: "my.name.space.controls",
      aggregations: {
        items: {
          type: "sap.m.ListItemBase",
          multiple: true,
          forwarding: { idSuffix: "--list", aggregation: "items" }
        }
      },
      properties: {
        label: { type: "string", defaultValue: "" },
        text: { type: "string", defaultValue: "" },
        noDataText: { type: "string", defaultValue: "No data" }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

And MyControl.control.xml

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m"
                         xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
  <VBox class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom">
    <Label id="textLabel"
           text="{$this>label}"
           class="sapUiTinyMarginEnd"
           labelFor="text"
           visible="{= ${$this>text} !== '' }" />
    <Text id="text"
          text="{$this>text}"
          visible="{= ${$this>text} !== '' }" />

    <Label id="listLabel"
           text="{$this>label}"
           class="sapUiTinyMarginEnd"
           labelFor="list"
           visible="{= ${$this>text} === '' }" />
    <List id="list"
          class="tagList"
          enableBusyIndicator="true"
          backgroundDesign="Transparent"
          growing="false"
          showSeparators="None"
          noDataText="{$this>noDataText}"
          visible="{= ${$this>text} === '' }" />
  </VBox>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Then for usage make sure to import the namespace

```
<mvc:View
  xmlns:reuse="my.name.space.controls"
  ...  
  <reuse:MyControl id="asd"
                      label="{i18n>asd}"
                      text="{odata>asd}" />
  ...
```

Comment: I was hoping i'd find the time to test this, but it doesn't look like it. It's much too complex to do what I've been trying to do, but when it comes to what my question was, this is probably the best answer I'll get for the time being. I really hope SAP will improve on this and implement a way of reusable components that compares to what other frameworks offer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A bit old topic, but you can also use binding.

First in your controller create model or just use or add property in existing one:

```
const customModelData = {"someTestProperty": "test"};
const customModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(customModelData);
this.getView().setModel(customModel, "newCustomModelName");
```

And in your view bind this model

```
<core:Fragment fragmentName="someFragmentName" type="XML" binding="{newCustomModelName>/}" />
```

And this way you can use "someTestProperty" value directly in your fragment for example like this (using expression binding):

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <Text text="Another test" visible="{= ${'someTestProperty'} === 'test' }">
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```